# vb.net creating table. using textbox.text for the per column of table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a program that add new employee it adds there personal information and there benefits id (ex. tax number). but i want to do is create a new table for there salary by making a new table and the columns will be there benefits id (ex.tax number) but i want to create the table automatically after the new employee is added here is my code if it will help you:

BTW IM GETTING A MESSAGEBOX THAT SHOW "incorrect syntax near '@idd'.

```
     Dim add As String = String.Empty
    add &= "insert into rec_member(firstname,middlename,lastname,age,birthday,pagibig,philhealth,sss,tin,department)"
    add &= "values "
    add &= "(@first,@middle,@last,@age,@bday,@pagibig,@philhealth,@sss,@tin,@dept);select scope_identity()"

    Dim benefits As String = String.Empty
    benefits &= "create table @idd(" & _
    "pagibig(@ibig) integer not null, " & _
    "philhealth(@phil) integer not null," & _
    "sss(@rsss) integer not null," & _
    "tin(@rtin) integer not null)"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("server=WIN10;database=add_member;user=hradmin;password=admin;")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = add
                .Parameters.Add("@first", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = afirstname.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@middle", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = amiddlename.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@last", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = alastname.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aage.Value
                .Parameters.Add("@bday", SqlDbType.Date).Value = abirthday.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@pagibig", SqlDbType.Int).Value = apagibig.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@philhealth", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aphilhealth.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@sss", SqlDbType.Int).Value = asss.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@tin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = atin.Text
                .Parameters.Add("@dept", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = adepartment.SelectedItem
            End With


                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    If afirstname.Text.Length < 2 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the FIRST NAME")
                    ElseIf amiddlename.Text.Length < 2 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the MIDDLE NAME")
                    ElseIf alastname.Text.Length < 2 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the LAST NAME")
                    ElseIf aage.Value < 16 Then
                        MsgBox("Age must be appropriate")
                    ElseIf abirthday.Text > "1997-01-01" Then
                        MsgBox("Please select a birthday")
                    ElseIf apagibig.Text.Length < 5 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the PAG-IBIG")
                    ElseIf adepartment.SelectedItem = "" Then
                        MsgBox("Please Select a Department")
                    ElseIf aphilhealth.Text.Length < 5 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the PHILHEALTH")
                    ElseIf asss.Text.Length < 5 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on th SSS")
                    ElseIf atin.Text.Length < 5 Then
                        MsgBox("Please input more value on the TIN")
                    Else

                        Dim id As Integer = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                        MsgBox("NEW EMPLOYEE ADDED" & Environment.NewLine &
                               "ID NUMBER:" & id & Environment.NewLine &
                               "FIRST NAME:" & afirstname.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "MIDDLE NAME:" & amiddlename.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "LAST NAME:" & alastname.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "AGE:" & aage.Value & Environment.NewLine &
                               "BIRTHDAY:" & abirthday.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "PAG-IBIG:" & apagibig.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "PHIL-HEALTH:" & aphilhealth.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "SSS:" & asss.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "TIN:" & atin.Text & Environment.NewLine &
                               "DEPARTMENT:" & adepartment.SelectedItem & Environment.NewLine
                               )

                    Using cmd1 As New SqlCommand
                        With cmd1
                               .Connection = conn
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = benefits
                            .Parameters.Add("@idd", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
                            .Parameters.Add("@ibig", SqlDbType.Int).Value = apagibig.Text
                            .Parameters.Add("@phil", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aphilhealth.Text
                            .Parameters.Add("@rsss", SqlDbType.Int).Value = asss.Text
                            .Parameters.Add("@rtin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = atin.Text
                        End With

                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        MsgBox("New Table is Set for new employee")
                    End Using
                End If
                afirstname.Clear()
                amiddlename.Clear()
                alastname.Clear()
                aage.Value = 0
                abirthday.Text = "1997-01-01"
                apagibig.Clear()
                adepartment.ResetText()
                aphilhealth.Clear()
                asss.Clear()
                atin.Clear()
                conn.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try


            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: You're adding your parameters incorrectly. Read the relevant documentation to learn the difference between `Add` and `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that you're using `Add` for the first parameter but `AddWithValue` for all the rest without changing the syntax. Again, learn how they each work.

Comment: oh wait let me edit it sorry.

Comment: You don't intend to create a new table for each new employee, do you? There is a tutorial on Microsoft's website on creating tables in code but I think it would be easier to do it in SSMS. You have opened your connection and then put up message boxes which wait for user to respond. User could have gone to lunch and you are holding open a connection. Do your verification before you open a connection and set parameter values. cmd.ExecuteScalar will not return an ID unless you have included a final SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); after your insert

Comment: uhmm yes i intend to create a new table. there ID NUMBER(PRIMARY KEY) will be there table name and the other that has been inserted will be there column name after it added the new employee.

Comment: im testing my self in coding so there's no need yet for that verification that you have said i think i will add that later.

Comment: A different table for each user is a wholly unsustainable model and very much ***not*** how a DB is supposed to be used.  You should also read the various comments  very carefully - you already have a stack of validation statements in that mess of code: why would you check the data (the length of a name for instance) *after* you have opened the DB, created params etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

```
create table @idd ...
```

you cant send command with non static table-name.

for this, you need build the command-text with tokens:

```
benefits &= "create table {0}(" & _
"pagibig(@ibig) integer not null, " & _
"philhealth(@phil) integer not null," & _
"sss(@rsss) integer not null," & _
"tin(@rtin) integer not null)"
```

and:

```
Using cmd1 As New SqlCommand
    With cmd1
        .Connection = conn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = String.Format(benefits, id)
        .Parameters.Add("@ibig", SqlDbType.Int).Value = apagibig.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@phil", SqlDbType.Int).Value = aphilhealth.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@rsss", SqlDbType.Int).Value = asss.Text
        .Parameters.Add("@rtin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = atin.Text
```

Comment: is there a way to make my the ID NUMBER to be a table name?

Comment: @Camorra yes... my code example do this. the `{0}` token its replaced with the `id` variable.

Comment: what is this code?    `.CommandText = String.Format(benefits, id)`. i quite dont understand it.

Comment: its adding new employee but it doesnt create the table an error message show "incorrect syntax near '1020'.

Comment: @Camorra, this because the table name must strat with non-numeric char. you can write: `String.Format(benefits, "t_" +  id)`

Comment: it doesnt create new table in my database

Comment: i have another error the _definition for column 'pagibig' must include a data type_.